# Spark add new column with value form previous some columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame like this:

```
+----------+---+
|   code   |idn|
+----------+---+
|   [I0478]|  0|
|   [B0527]|  1|
|   [C0798]|  2|
|   [C0059]|  3|
|   [I0767]|  4|
|   [I1001]|  5|
|   [C0446]|  6|
+----------+---+
```

And i want to add new column to DataFrame

```
+----------+---+------+
|   code   |idn| item |
+----------+---+------+
|   [I0478]|  0| I0478|
|   [B0527]|  1| B0527|
|   [C0798]|  2| C0798|
|   [C0059]|  3| C0059|
|   [I0767]|  4| I0767|
|   [I1001]|  5| I1001|
|   [C0446]|  6| C0446|
+----------+---+------+
```

Please help me do this!

Answer (score 3):

Use `[]`:

```
df.withColumn("item", df["item"][0])
```

Comment: AnalysisException: u"Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;"

Comment: @PhongNguyen I had the same issue even with `[]`. Turned out my column was actually `Struct` rather than `Array`..

Answer (score 1):

So the problem will be evident if you look at the schema - the column you are trying to subset is not an array. So the solution is to .* expand the column.

```
df.select('code.*', 'idn')
```

Answer (score 1):

python

```
import pandas as pd


array = {'code': [['I0478'],['B0527'], ['C0798'], ['C0059'], ['I0767'], ['I1001'], ['C0446']], 'idn':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}


df = pd.DataFrame(array)

df['item'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row.code).lstrip('[').rstrip(']').strip("'").strip(), axis= 1)


print(df)
```

Comment: The question is about apache-spark, not pandas.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.withColumn("item", df["code"][0])
```

If the "item" column is Array type, if it's Struct of string, you may need to inspect the key of the element of item by df.select("code").collect()[0], see what key(string) it has.